# How do I use a class method in a separate program?

Tags: python, class

I have a quite a bit of confusion on how to use classes. I understand *what* they are, and *why* they should be used, just not how. For example, we're given a pre-made class (I'll call it class `Class_1(object)` to keep things simple) with a few functions (methods, right?) and variables in it.

```
class Class_1(object):

    var_1= [a,b,c]
    var_2= [x,y,z]
    var_3= {n:[o,p],g:[h,i]}

    def method_1(self):
        '''here's a method'''
```

(As a side note, the `Class_1(object)` does have the `__init__(self):` method already done.)

Now, in a separate program, I've imported the file that contains that class at the top of the program, but how do I use methods or variables from the class? For example, if I want to check a user input against a value in `var_1`, how would I do that?

I've gotten better with functions in general, but calling on classes and methods is as clear as mud.

Edit: Realized I said "methods" instead of "variables" when I actually need both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the class, you need to create an class instance from the separate file:

```
import filename1
class1 = filename1.Class_1()
```

With the instance, you can then access the member variables:

```
value1 = class1.method_1
```

Comment: Simple enough. Thanks!

Comment: @Marty glad to help!